# Debugging jQuery ajax 500 Internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax

My working CodeIgniter site is giving a 500 Internal Server Error while hosting it on MediaTemple. It is happening during a jQuery Ajax call.

I have no idea what could have gone wrong. Is the error from the controller or the model? My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('invites/save_email') ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg) {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('invites/moreinvites')?>"
        return true;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

xhr.responseText has returned me `<p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>`. But what does that mean?

Comment: I don't understand why you have msg in `success: function(msg)` if you don't even use it in this function? Check if variable posted to/received from controller are of good type.

Comment: 500 Means a server error, the problem is not with your jQuery code, the problem is with the server.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ok I understand that problem is with server code. But how I am going to debug it?

Comment: I think for this ajax call you use 'Post', while how did you implement you controller, does it accept 'Post' call or 'Get' call? and was the url mapped in your controller?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can try using `alert(xhr.responseText);` or `console.log(xhr.responseText);` (the later will show up in your browser console e.g. firebug) in your error callback, doing so you can get the message associated with the exception (if any).

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
```

or

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
           console.log(thrownError);
       }
```

Comment: good answer not a direct one but has taken me towards solution. Thanks

Comment: For others with direct answer that worked for me. Give IIS_IUSRS access to write/modify to folder security where placing the file. The responseText helped pinpoint error to this.

Comment: perfect debug code for jquery POST methods that maybe have some errors in the .php file! +1 !

Answer (score 0):

Please see my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786593/14533). It is a full explanation on how to do ajax debugging with CodeIgniter and jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the webconfig file to receive POST request.

```
 <system.web>

    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
 </system.web>
```